# Abnormal behaviour of scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using GCC complier. In my program I have used 3 `scanf`s, but while executing it only performs 2 `scanf`s. Why is it skipping 1 `scanf`? It's only executing the else condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int h, c, t;
    printf("tensile");
    scanf("%d", &h);
    printf("tensile1");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("tensile2");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    if( h > 50 && c > 0.7 && t > 5600)
        printf("HI");
    else
        printf("bye");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only enter whole numbers with `%d`, I suspect you're typing a decimal number...

Comment: What are you supplying as input for these `scanf`s?

Answer (score 2):

You defined `c` as an `int` and compared it to `0.7`. Even ignoring any `scanf` issues, that doesn't make much sense. Decide for each of your variables whether it should hold only whole numbers or (possibly fractional) real numbers.  For whole numbers, you probably want `int`. For real numbers, you probably want `double`. And then you need to use the proper format for `scanf`, depending on the type of the variable. Read your `scanf` documentation for details.

With the `"%d"` format, `scanf` will read a single integer (after skipping any whitespace, including newlines), and then stop. If the input is `"12.34"`, it will read the `"12"`, store `12` in the variable, and leave the `".34"` in the input stream. Later calls to `scanf` with `"%d"` will fail when they see the `'.'` character. Use one of the floating-point formats to read a variable of type `double` and permit inputs like `"12.34"`.

`scanf` returns a result indicating how many items it successfully read, or an error indication. You should test that result so your program will detect errors rather than blindly continuing to run with bad data.

Showing us *exactly* (i.e., copy-and-paste) the input you gave to your program would have made it easier to answer your question.

Printing the values of your variables and the result returned by `scanf` would have helped *you* understand what's going on -- or you can examine the values in a debugger if one is available.

Some things to watch out for: `scanf` will report failure on input syntax errors (e.g., if it's looking for a real number and you enter `"foobar"`), but it won't necessarily diagnose overflows. If you enter `1.0e99999999` for a floating-point input, the behavior is *undefined*. The only real way to avoid that problem is to avoid using `scanf` for numeric input. (IMHO this is a flaw in the way the C standard defines the `*scanf` functions.)

Floating-point comparisons are notoriously unreliable. If `c` is a floating-point variable, `c > 0.7` could be either true or false, since the value `0.7` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point.

Answer (score 1):

Change the data type of variable c to float and use %f as format specifier. It is skipping because you are providing float value to an integer variable